# gnu make spaces in directory names vpath

Tags: c++, c, makefile, gnu

We've been trying unsuccessfully to make `VPATH` or `vpath` search directories containing space characters.

My makefile contains:

```
vpath %cpp RTW/ModelRTW RTW/StandardTests RTW/TestFramework RTW/TestFromFile ../../../CommonCode ../04_Model/DLib/ ../04 Model/ELib/
```

`make -p` returns:

```
.
.
vpath %cpp RTW/ModelRTW:RTW/StandardTests:RTW/TestFramework:RTW/TestFromFile:../../../CommonCode:../04_Model/DLib
```

I have tried quoting, escaping '\ ' and several other incarnations to no avail.

Any help would be greatfully accepted.

Ed

Comment: I can find comments from several years ago saying that it is not supported. It's likely that this is still the case. Can you implement your makefile so that vpath is not needed?

Comment: Make documentation specifically says `vpath` spaces are considered path separators, the [source](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/make.git/plain/vpath.c) doesn't seem to reveal any way of changing this behavior (perhaps creating a custom locale that changes the behavior of `isspace` might work, it'll probably break just about everything else though).

Comment: You cannot write makefiles for paths containing whitespace.  vpath is only a minor tip of a very large iceberg.  Paths containing spaces are tricky to work with for all different types of tools, not just make.  It's best to avoid them.

Answer (score 2):

Sadly, it is a [very old known defect, #712](http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?712), and people have looked in to it a few times since it was reported in 2002.

GNU make doesn't handle spaces in names, and never has.

If you do attempt to patch it you will have a serious challenge ahead, since an enormous number of projects rely on it. Those who need whitespace support move to more advanced build systems. Over the decades there have been many build script tools, but make still sticks around despite many major problems. The make format of tabs and spaces has been annoying developers for almost 40 years.

The source is available, feel free to attempt to patch it if you want. Most developers who try end up giving up or making yet another build script system.

Comment: GNU make has supported alternative recipe introduction characters (other than TAB) since version 3.82 (released in 2010).

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to write an m-script to copy the file(s) to the build directory where path is space-free.
If you use Simulink then the m-script is invoked at "before_make" hook.

Comment: Add some description.